# Filtering joined tables messes up the sql Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm having problems building up a query with filters.

My table structure is **Log Header** with **Driver Truck** and **Creator** tables related and a child table **Log Details**.

Then there is a method to get those related data with options to filter on Log header dates, and filters based on the related tables (Driver or truck).

Now when the user filters only on the header table the data is properly loaded, however when the user filters the related truck or driver then i'm getting a weird error that sql cannot find the column names.

So i decided to run the profiler and detect the query Ef is sending and i found a funny result, that ef includes column's on wrong tables!.

So this is the c# code

```
var h = db.LogHeader.AsQueryable();

        if (OrderNumber == null)
        {
            if (fromDate != DateTime.MinValue) { h = h.Where(l => l.DateTime >= fromDate); }
            if (toDate != DateTime.MinValue) { h = h.Where(l => l.DateTime <= toDate); }
            if (LogID != null) { h = h.Where(l => l.LogHeaderID == LogID); }
            if (Driver != "0") { h = h.Where(l => l.Driver.DriverID.ToString() == Driver); }
            if (Truck != "0") { h = h.Where(l => l.Truck.TruckID.ToString() == Truck); }
            if (Shipped != "") { h = h.Where(l => l.Shipped == Convert.ToBoolean(Shipped)); }

            h = h.Take(rowCount ?? 25);
        }
        else
        {
            h = h.Where(d => d.LogDetails.Any(o => o.OrderNumber == OrderNumber));
        }

        var list = from lh in h
                   select new TruckHistoryViewModel
                   {
                       id = lh.LogHeaderID,
                       DateValue = lh.DateTime.ToString("M/d/yy"),
                       Time = lh.DateTime.ToString("h:mm tt"),
                       Driver = lh.Driver.FullName,
                       DriverID = lh.Driver.DriverID,
                       Truck = lh.Truck.TruckDescription,
                       Stops = lh.Stops,
                       DateAndTime = lh.DateTime,
                       LoaderName = lh.LoaderName,
                       Notes = lh.Notes,
                       CreatedBy = lh.CreatedBy.FullName,
                       Shipped = lh.Shipped == true ? "Yes" : "No",
                       OrderList = lh.LogDetails.Select(d => new LogDetailsViewModel
                       {
                           LogHeaderID = d.LogHeaderID ,
                           OrderNumber = d.OrderNumber,
                           StopNumber = d.StopNumber,
                           WorkComplete = d.Order.WorkComplete,
                           FollowUp = d.Order.FollowUp,
                           IsDouble = d.DubledOrderID != 0 ? true : false
                       })
                   };
```

And the sql query Ef send's That is working (when not filtering related data) is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [lh.CreatedBy].[CreateByNameID], [lh.CreatedBy].[Creater], [lh.CreatedBy].[Disabled], [lh.CreatedBy].[FullName], [lh.CreatedBy].[Loader], [lh.CreatedBy].[Picker], [lh.Truck].[TruckID], [lh.Truck].[Disabled], [lh.Truck].[TruckDescription], [lh.Truck].[TruckNumber], [lh.Driver].[DriverID], [lh.Driver].[Disabled], [lh.Driver].[FirstName], [lh.Driver].[LastName], [lh.Driver].[Notes], [lh.Driver].[PhoneNumber], [t].[LogHeaderID], [t].[DateTime], [lh.Driver].[DriverID], [t].[Stops], [t].[LoaderName], [t].[Notes], CASE
WHEN [t].[Shipped] = 1
THEN N''Yes'' ELSE N''No''
END
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@__p_3) [l0].*
    FROM [LogHeader] AS [l0]
    WHERE (([l0].[DateTime] >= @__fromDate_0) AND ([l0].[DateTime] <= @__toDate_1)) AND ([l0].[Shipped] = @__ToBoolean_2)
) AS [t]
LEFT JOIN [CreatedByName] AS [lh.CreatedBy] ON [t].[CreatedByCreateByNameID] = [lh.CreatedBy].[CreateByNameID]
LEFT JOIN [Trucks] AS [lh.Truck] ON [t].[TruckID] = [lh.Truck].[TruckID]
LEFT JOIN [Drivers] AS [lh.Driver] ON [t].[DriverID] = [lh.Driver].[DriverID]
ORDER BY [t].[CreatedByCreateByNameID], [t].[TruckID], [t].[DriverID]',N'@__p_3 int,@__fromDate_0 datetime2(7),@__toDate_1 datetime2(7),@__ToBoolean_2 bit',@__p_3=30,@__fromDate_0='2017-08-15 00:00:00',@__toDate_1='2017-08-17 00:00:00',@__ToBoolean_2=0
```

But when filtering related tables it's getting a funny query with a few column names that does not exists or exists in another table:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [l].[LogHeaderID], [l].[CreatedByCreateByNameID], [l].[CreatedDate], [l].[DateTime], [l].[DriverID], [l].[LoaderName], [l].[Notes], [l].[Shipped], [l].[Stops], [l].[TruckID], [l.Truck].[TruckID], [l.Truck].[Disabled], [l.Truck].[TruckDescription], [l.Truck].[TruckNumber], [l.Truck].[CreatedByCreateByNameID], [l.Truck].[DriverID], [l.Truck].[LogHeaderID], [l.Truck].[DateTime], [l.Truck].[Stops], [l.Truck].[LoaderName], [l.Truck].[Notes], [l.Truck].[Shipped]
FROM [LogHeader] AS [l]
LEFT JOIN [Trucks] AS [l.Truck] ON [l].[TruckID] = [l.Truck].[TruckID]
WHERE (([l].[DateTime] >= @__fromDate_0) AND ([l].[DateTime] <= @__toDate_1)) AND ([l].[Shipped] = @__ToBoolean_3)
ORDER BY [l].[TruckID]',N'@__fromDate_0 datetime2(7),@__toDate_1 datetime2(7),@__ToBoolean_3 bit',@__fromDate_0='2017-08-15 00:00:00',@__toDate_1='2017-08-17 00:00:00',@__ToBoolean_3=0
```

Error returned in ssms:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'CreatedByCreateByNameID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'DriverID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'LogHeaderID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'DateTime'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Stops'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'LoaderName'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Notes'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Shipped'.
```

For clarity i'll add the db context class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<LogHeader>().HasOne(t => t.Truck).WithMany(l => l.TruckLogs);
            builder.Entity<LogHeader>().HasOne(t => t.Driver).WithMany(l => l.DriverLogs);
            builder.Entity<LogHeader>().HasOne(t => t.CreatedBy).WithMany(l => l.LogHeaders);

            builder.Entity<LogDetails>().HasOne(o => o.Order).WithMany(o => o.LogDetails);

            builder.Entity<Order>().HasOne(o => o.Category).WithMany(c => c.Orders).HasForeignKey(c => c.CatagoryID);

            builder.Entity<CreatedBy>().ToTable("CreatedByName");
        }

        public DbSet<LogHeader> LogHeader { get; set;}
        public DbSet<LogDetails> LogDetails { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Truck> Trucks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Driver> Drivers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; internal set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Order { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CreatedBy> Creaters { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

So is anything wrong with my code? (or unlikely it's a bug in ef)

**Note:** I'm pretty new to EF, so if there any suggestions to the code i'll greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Most likely it's a EFC bug. What EFC version are you on?

Comment: Oh no! Please, don't let it be 2.0.0....

Comment: Now i'm using 1.1.1

Comment: EFC bug, most likely caused by client evaluation of the filter conditions containing `ToString()` call (like `l.Driver.DriverID.ToString() == Driver`). Either eliminate them by converting the value being compared to the type of the entity property(column), or upgrade to EFC 2.0 where this seem to be fixed (at least `ToString()` is translated to SQL).

Comment: Thanks, I'll upgrade to version 2 when i have a chance.